# How to calculate AWS IO cost for MySQL DB query & inserts?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am totally new to AWS and want to use EC2 instance, I have already gone through AWS faqs, pricing and cost calculator. But Apart from storage cost IO cost is not clear to me yet.

In my application I am supposed to have around 30-40 GB of database storage, so I assume following will be IO cost:

- IO cost will be querying the data which users will do during day
- Insert/update around 30-40 GB of data every night.

How can I estimate the cost of the above?

In addition to that, will indexing cost me storage + IO also?

At night I will parse 30-40 GB of XML data and insert (mostly update) tables data, so parsing will add computational cost extra? Though I will have micro instance with 100% cpu utilization.

Can anyone give some insight on this please

Comment: The only way to do this is to simulate your workload and see what happens. MySQL can decrease I/O if it has large enough memory caches to do work in. If not, the work is moved to disk.

Comment: Are you using the Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service) or are you installing the database yourself on Amazon EC2 with data stored on Amazon EBS? What type of EBS storage are you using (Magnetic, Provisioned, General Purpose)? When you refer to "IO cost", do you mean the monetary cost, or the amount of IO that will be required (and therefore used to determine your necessary disk speed)?

Comment: I plan to use Amazon RDS (MySQL), I suppose to calculate the monetary cost I will have to first estimate amount of IO, isn't it? But eventually I need monetary cost to see if this idea is feasible for me or not. 
Can you please have a look at my calculated cost here:
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=FRA&key=calc-9B03568E-285F-433A-9BD0-EB0CCEA26373